# Приравнивание числа к строке

Tags: c

Суть функции:считать строку из char(число в 10-системе счисления), затем число int приравнять к считанной строке.

Comment: Очень познавательно. А в чём вопрос?

Answer (score 5):

Можно использовать функцию atoi
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Answer (score 0):

```
int my_atoi(const char* s){

  for(; *s; ++s)

      n = n * 10 + (*s - '0'); 

  return n;

}
```

Comment: Хоть бы `n` сначала обнулили и и проверяли еще и `isdigit(*s)`.